# Removing magento cms page layout update from mobile theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-layout-xml

I'm using cms HomePage in magento to show my block.
It reuqires some `<action>`, so I'm adding it on layout update tab. It works fine, but...

This layout update is applied on mobile theme too, what is wrong behaviour. How can i prevent it?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple solution... What you want from action? Maybe there is another way for that ;)